# Specify VS extension installation directory name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

After installing extension in VS 2012 it is placed in `%userprofile%AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\` (or in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions` if it is installed for all users) and in folder with random name like "hilatg23.234" or "kcsuvnvi.qtq". Is there a way to specify the name of this folder and make this extension to install to folder like `%userprofile%AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\MY_EXTENSION_NAME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, don´t think so. The VSIX installer will always choose the installation directory automatically. If you want to let the user decide about the installation folder, you´d need to create a `MSI` installation package.

A while ago I answered another question regards the package registration; maybe some of the provided information might help to create such a setup. See post at: [MSI installed VSPackage is loaded in Experimental Instance only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094551/msi-installed-vspackage-is-loaded-in-experimental-instance-only)

If you just want to obtain the package installation folder at runtime, you can just get it from the package´s assembly codebase, like:

```
private static string ObtainInstallationFolder()
{
    Type packageType = typeof(MyPackage);
    Uri uri = new Uri(packageType.Assembly.CodeBase);
    var assemblyFileInfo = new FileInfo(uri.LocalPath);
    return assemblyFileInfo.Directory.FullName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

I use this api get vsix install physical path:

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

path = \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\...\Extensions\[install path]\xx.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the name of the Extensions<folder> with this msbuild property in your vsix project file:

`<ExtensionInstallationFolder>YourExtensionName</ExtensionInstallationFolder>`