# How to use content in .VSIX package?how to get vsix install path

Tags: c#, vsix

NOW I use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292351/including-content-files-in-csproj-that-are-outside-the-project-cone)add folder in .VSIX package.

```
<Content Include="..\..\MyContentFiles\**\*.*">
  <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

After I installed the VSIX, I can find extension in this path
`\Users<UserName>\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0Exp\Extensions\Microsoft\<GPName>`
but I can't get the folder path in vsix code(some python script in this folder,the extension need get this folder install path).

I try use ：

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName,
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory,
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory,
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase
```

but they all return this path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE...

**so how to get vsix install path and how to use content in .VSIX?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19708737/17034

Answer (score 3):

The question has been solved now.

I use this api get vsix install physical path：

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

path = \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio...\Extensions[install path]\xx.dll